How does a motorbike ride on walls?
I was looking at this question on the PAT 2020 and when looking at the answer I didn't understand why friction can be ignored. I first thought that friction was cancelling out weight to prevent it from sliding vertically but that wouldn't stop it from falling over. However then the only force acting on the bike would be the normal which should be normal to the wall correct?
I would love for someone to provide me with an explanation of the answer, thank you in advanced.


Who says that friction can be ignored?  If this is in the solution, please post the solution.

There are three forces acting on the bike. It's weight (vertically down through the centre of mass), the friction of the tyres on the wall (vertically up through the point of contact), and the centripetal force keeping it going in a cercle (horizontally through the point of contact).
The friction is equal to the weight so that it doesn't fall down or rise up.
The centripetal force and friction each form a turning moment around the bike's centre of mass (COM). The friction pushing the bike to rotate  more horizontal, the centripetal force pushing it more vertical. These are opposite and equal so the bike's circling is stable.
At higher speeds the bike will be more horizontal; to increase the horizontal distance from the COM to the friction, decrease the vertical distance from the COM to the centripetal force  and so balance the increased centripetal force due to the faster speed around the track.
At lower speeds the bike will be more vertical but there is a limit as the handlebars would hit the wall with possibly unpleasant consequences.

I think your choice of words may be confusing. There is no actual, separate "centripetal force" acting on the bike as there is gravity, friction, etc. The net of all the actual forces toward the center of the circle provides the centripetal force required to maintain circular motion.
